# PHP - How to parse string information into usable form from database

Tags: php, database-design, key-value

I am working on a web-app system that has multiple apps, each with a Primary Key to identify them. Each user also has a security level tied to an app, for instance App #1 with a security level of 5. I want to store all the app / security information in the database as a token, and then retrieve that information to store it in Session.

So given the following apps:

1. Task App
2. Email App
3. Notes App

and a user that has security level 3, 5, and 7 respectively, the token will be stored as:

```
1.3|2.5|3.7.
```

My question is, how do I retrieve that data in a usable form? I was thinking of having it in an array, with the array key of the App ID, like `somearray[1] = 3`, `somearray[2] = 5`, etc, but I have no idea how to handle this.

I'm early in development on this part, so I have a very open mind towards suggestions. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the token will be stored as:
>
> 1.3|2.5|3.7.

Why don't you store security levels in a database ? It will be much more easy to manage. I could imagine few tables like the following:

```
App
--------
id
name
....

Users
--------
id
name
email
...

App_users_permissions
--------
id
app_id (references App.id)
user_id (references Users.id)
level
```

Then, you could do a simple query like:

```
SELECT level FROM App_users_permissions WHERE user_id = 1 AND app_id = 2
```

This query would then return the current previlege id, for a given app id and user id.

I think that would be the easiest way to manage this.

Comment: The idea was that the string would only require one query, and one return, minimizing database work, and shifting the burden to PHP. A user could literally have hundreds of apps, would the app_users_permissions method still be better?

Comment: Yes, database servers are designed to handle a such amount of data. Parsing a string will result in slow performances and it was **not** designed to store data like you want to do. I still think using a database would be the best way to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

You should really redesign your database as suggested by [Pierre-Olivier Bourgeois](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9950297/43959).

If you want to stick with the described format, you could use `preg_match_all()`:

```
$subject = '1.3|2.5|3.7.';
$pattern = '=(\d+)\.(\d+)=';
$result = preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $subpattern, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($subpattern as $match) {
    $out[$match[1]] = $match[2];
}
print_r($out);
```

Answer (score 0):

you you *really* want to store this things as one string (you shouldn't), you could use [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to take it apart again.

anyway, the much better solution would be to [properly normalize your database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) ([step-to-step guide for this](http://www.phlonx.com/resources/nf3/)).

Answer (score 0):

Explode

```
Item = explode('|',token);

List(key,val) = explode('.',Item);

Echo List, val
```